# Android fragment listview Tablayout Item Onclick

Tags: android, listview, tabs, fragment, onclicklistener

I just started a program in android and I use android studio 2.3.3 for development.

Summary of my application: I created a tablayout with three fragment and each has a listview. Now I would like to be able to click on an item to display the details in another view.

I try several formulas but nothing. I need your help please.

Comment: Do you have some code ?

Comment: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {